# Bootstrap Datepicker Convert numbers to Persian lang

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding the translation of jQuery Bootstrap Datepicker.

On original bootstrap-datepicker I have:

```
monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'], // Names of months for drop-down and formatting
monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], // For formatting
dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'], // For formatting
dayNamesShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'], // For formatting
dayNamesMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'], // Column headings for days starting at Sunday
```

but there is no dayNumber: `['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']`

My question is, how can I implement this line translation to translate the numbers to persian symbols ?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: are you using the jquery ui one?

Comment: yes, im using also jquery-ui

Comment: I think Daniel meant asking what datepicker are you using.

Comment: Bootstrap datepicker http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

The elements that represent the calendar days are built inside a 'while' loop, so you'll have to do a couple of changes to the plugin. A quick way of achieving the desired result is to create a function to convert the digits to Persian and store the decimal values in a custom attribute, so that most of the logic remains unaltered :

```
function convert(num) {

    var persian = {
      0: '۰',
      1: '۱',
      2: '۲',
      3: '۳',
      4: '۴',
      5: '۵',
      6: '۶',
      7: '۷',
      8: '۸',
      9: '۹'
    };

    var out = '';
    for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
      out = out + persian[num[i]];
    }

    return out;
}
```

To change the numbers in the calendar widget, update lines 808 and 997:

```
//html.push('<td class="' + clsName.join(' ') + '"' + (tooltip ? ' title="' + tooltip + '"' : '') + '>' + prevMonth.getUTCDate() + '</td>');
html.push('<td data-day="'+prevMonth.getUTCDate()+'" class="' + clsName.join(' ') + '"' + (tooltip ? ' title="' + tooltip + '"' : '') + '>' + convert(String(prevMonth.getUTCDate())) + '</td>');

...

//day = parseInt(target.text(), 10) || 1;
day = target.data("day");
```

To change the numbers in the input field, add after line 1600:

```
date[1] = convert(String(date[1]));
date[3] = convert(String(date[3]));
date[5] = convert(String(date[5]));
```

A working example:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r_costa/j15bheL4/)